# Convertir hexadecimal numérico string a bytes python

Tags: python-3.x

No se si el titulo esta especifico pero tengo un problema al convertir un string de hexadecimal a bytes, he utilizado la función bytes.fromhex y funciona cuando el hexadecimal es con caracteres pero cuando tiene un numero que es hexadecimal no funciona, ejemplo:

```
>>>bytes.fromhex('ab')
b'\xab'
>>>bytes.fromhex('32')
b'2'
```

No se si estoy haciendo algo mal pero según yo debería salirme b'\x32'

Agradezco a quien pueda ayudarme,
Cordial saludo

Comment: b'\x32' es equivalente a b'2', solo cambia como lo muestra (ya que al caracter '2' le corresponde el [codigo numerico ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Caracteres_imprimibles_ASCII) en hexadecimal 32).

Answer (score 0):

Quizás esto te sirva:

```
hexadecimal = '123abc'
print(bin(int(hexadecimal, 16))[2:])
#100100011101010111100

hexadecimal = 'ab'
print(bin(int(hexadecimal, 16))[2:])
#10101011

hexadecimal = '32'
print(bin(int(hexadecimal, 16))[2:])
# 110010
```

Los comentarios que hay debajo de los print, son sus respectivos resultados.